# Is it necessary to maintain certain order inside oozie action content?

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

When i tried to run oozie hive action with the following code

```
<action name="Hive-Node">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
        <prepare>
            <mkdir path="${nameNode}/hive/output"/>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>hive.insert.into.multilevel.dirs</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
                <value>${hbaseZooQuorum}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <script>${HIVE_QUERY_FILE}</script>
    </hive>
    <ok to="End" />
    <error to="Fail" />
</action>
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'prepare'. One of '{"uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2":configuration, "uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2":script}' is expected.
```

But after I modified the order of declaring tags inside hive action i.e moved `<job-xml>...</job-xml>` after `<prepare>...</prepare>`, it works fine.

Is it necessary to follow those order(s) inside oozie actions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Oozie Hive Action Documentation](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/DG_HiveActionExtension.html#Hive_Action_Schema_Version_0.2),

The schema uses,

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="job-tracker" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="name-node" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="prepare" type="hive:PREPARE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="job-xml" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="configuration" type="hive:CONFIGURATION" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="script" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="param" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="file" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="archive" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

the element `xs:sequence` which [as per W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp),

> The **sequence element** specifies that the child elements **must appear in
>   a sequence**. Each child element can occur from 0 to any number of
>   times.

And we can see as per the schema for Hive-Action `<prepare>` comes before `<job-xml>` in sequence